# Error spotting : Maya wasn't promoted to the post of a manager till for a few months of her resignation

Tags: exam-questions, error

> Maya wasn't promoted to (A) the post of a manager (B) till for a few
>   months of her resignation. (C) No error (D)

What's the error in the above sentence ?
My book says error is in part C but isn't the B part also wrong ? Shouldn't the  correct form be *the post of manager* ?

What's the error in part C ? Do we need to remove *for* from it to correct the sentence ?

So the overall correct form should be

Maya wasn't promoted to the post of manager till a few months of her resignation.

Comment: The B part is also unidiomatic, as you say.  **till *within* a few ...**

Comment: Part (C) is the worse of the errors, but B and C are both wrong, as you say. I would rephrase (C) to _until a few months before her resignation._

Answer (score 1):

The word "till" refers to a single point in time that acts as a boundary. But "for a few months" is a span of time. The two can't be used together.